# What is wrong with my fit?

Tags: fitting, warning-messages

I am trying to fit the following data:

```
data = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/gHdYLCbA", "Table"]
```

I use the following code:

```
fit = Piecewise[{{a1 Sqrt[x], x < 0.001}, {a2/x Log[1 + a4/x + a5 x], 
     0.001 < x < 2}}];
model = NonlinearModelFit[data, fit, {a1, a2, a4, a5}, x]
```

but I get the error:

> NonlinearModelFit::nrlnum: "The function value {-15.65+0.\
>   I,-137.718+0.\ I,-106.484+0.\ I,-89.1487+0.\ I,-78.4745+0.\
>   I,-66.5805+0.\ I,-60.5891+0.\ I,-57.1656+0.\ I,-54.7171+0.\
>   I,-51.1795+0.\ I,<<31>>,-101.868-0.291172\ I,-97.1306-0.249576\
>   I,-92.5161-0.218379\ I,-88.3471-0.194115\ I,-84.6393-0.174703\
>   I,-81.3796-0.158821\ I,-78.5062-0.145586\ I,-75.9376-0.134387\
>   I,-73.6229-0.124788\ I,<<82>>} is not a list of real numbers with
>   dimensions {132} at {a1,a2,a4,a5} = {1.,-0.0278049,0.935645,-13251.8}"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to constrain the values of your parameters, because now, the `Fit`ting function tries the `Log` of something negative, giving imaginary numbers. Something like `NonlinearModelFit[data, {fit, a4 > 0 && a5 > 0}, {a1, a2, a4, a5}, x]` should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do a rational approximation in `Sqrt[x]`, which fits quite good:

```
xy={{0.001, 15.65}, {0.0015, 18.99}, {0.002, 21.79}, {0.0025,24.25}, {0.003, 26.48}, {0.004, 30.41}, {0.005, 33.88}, {0.006,37.01}, {0.007, 39.88}, {0.008, 42.56}, {0.009, 45.07}, {0.01,47.45}, {0.0125, 52.26}, {0.015, 56.5}, {0.0175, 60.33}, {0.02,63.83}, {0.0225, 67.05}, {0.025, 70.03}, {0.0275, 72.8}, {0.03,75.39}, {0.035, 80.1}, {0.04, 84.26}, {0.045, 87.96}, {0.05,91.25}, {0.055, 94.19}, {0.06, 96.8}, {0.065, 99.12}, {0.07,101.2}, {0.075, 103.}, {0.08, 104.6}, {0.085, 106.}, {0.09, 107.2}, {0.095, 108.3}, {0.1, 109.2}, {0.125, 111.8}, {0.15,112.2}, {0.175, 111.4}, {0.2, 109.8}, {0.225, 107.8}, {0.25,105.6}, {0.275, 103.4}, {0.3, 101.1}, {0.35, 96.46}, {0.4,91.92}, {0.45, 87.81}, {0.5, 84.15}, {0.55, 80.93}, {0.6,78.09}, {0.65, 75.55}, {0.7, 73.26}, {0.75, 71.18}, {0.8,69.28}, {0.85, 67.53}, {0.9, 65.9}, {0.95, 64.39}, {1.,62.97}, {1.25, 57.03}, {1.5, 52.43}, {1.75, 48.72}, {2.,45.62}, {2.25, 42.98}}

nml = NonlinearModelFit[ xy ,Sqrt[x] (1 + a Sqrt[x])/(b + c Sqrt[x] + d Sqrt[x]^2), {a, b, c,d }, x]
Show[{Plot[Normal[nml], {x, 0, 2.25}], ListPlot[xy ]},PlotLabel -> Normal[nml]]
```

[image]