# How to improve my fit?

Tags: fitting

I use the following code to fit some data given [in a previous question of mine:](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/179436/8822)

```
data = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/gHdYLCbA", "Table"]

fit = Piecewise[{{a1 Sqrt[x], x < 10^4}, {(
     a3/x Log[1 + a4/x + a5 x]*a2 x^0.45)/(
     a3/x Log[1 + a4/x + a5 x] + a2 x^0.45), 10^4 < x < 2*10^6}}];
model = NonlinearModelFit[
  Transpose[{data[[All, 1]]*10^6, data[[All, 2]]*19.32}], {fit, 
   a4 > 0 && a5 > 0}, {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5}, x, Method -> "NMinimize", 
  MaxIterations -> 1000]

Show[ListLogLogPlot[
  Transpose[{data[[All, 1]]*10^6, data[[All, 2]]*19.32}], 
  PlotRange -> All], 
 LogLogPlot[model[x], {x, 100, 2000000}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}]]
```

The result is

[image]

How can I improve the fit?

Comment: You probably want to rescale your data back to values on the order of 1 before you fit. Nonlinear models are difficult to fit when the values are all over the place. Furthermore, the fact that you're plotting the data in log-log space indicates that you should probably not fit `y` as a function of `x`, but `Log[y]` as a function of `Log[x]`. If you fit `y[x]`, then the fit will only be sensitive to the large values of `y`, which is precisely what you're seeing here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Quantile Regression. Below is code that uses the (recently proclaimed) package [MonadicQuantileRegression.m](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2018/08/01/a-monad-for-quantile-regression-workflows/).

I specified a special list of B-spline basis knots in order to avoid aliasing effects. The relative errors plot shows a good fit. Then regression function is then taken out of the monad and its piecewise form is simplified.

```
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antononcube/\
MathematicaForPrediction/master/MonadicProgramming/\
MonadicQuantileRegression.m"]
```

[image]

```
data = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/gHdYLCbA", "Table"];

p =
  QRMonUnit[data]⟹
   QRMonEchoDataSummary⟹
   QRMonQuantileRegression[Join[Range[0, 1, 0.1], Range[1.1, 1.1 Max[data[[All, 1]]], 0.3]],0.5]⟹
   QRMonPlot⟹
   QRMonErrorPlots;
```

[image]

```
fitFunc = First[p⟹QRMonTakeRegressionFunctions][x];
PiecewiseExpand[fitFunc]
```

[image]